# No puedo ejecutar ningun comando rails, en ubuntu 18.04 64 bits

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Recien instalé la version 2.5.5 de ruby con rvm install `rvm install "ruby-2.5.5"` y al ejecuar cualquier comando rails me da el mismo error:

```
$ rails --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
    22: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
    21: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    20: from /home/elorat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    19: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:309:in `activate_bin_path'
    18: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:309:in `synchronize'
    17: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:311:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    16: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:243:in `finish_resolve'
    15: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:408:in `resolve_current'
    14: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:396:in `resolve'
    13: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:188:in `resolve'
    12: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:42:in `resolve'
    11: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:64:in `resolve'
    10: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:106:in `start_resolution'
     9: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:165:in `initial_state'
     8: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:51:in `sort_dependencies'
     7: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:69:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
     6: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:52:in `block in sort_dependencies'
     5: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:277:in `sort_dependencies'
     4: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:277:in `with_index'
     3: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:277:in `sort_by'
     2: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:277:in `each'
     1: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:283:in `block in sort_dependencies'
/home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:231:in `search_for': Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'bundler (= 1.16.6)' (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)
```

He probado con estos comandos:

```
$ rails new appname
$ rails --help
$ rails -c
$ rails s
$ rails --version
```

Instalé y desinstalé la versión de `bundler 1.16.6`, en ambos casos me da el mismo error.

Tengo estas versiones de bundler:

```
$ gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (default: 2.0.2, default: 2.0.1)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
capistrano-bundler (1.6.0, 1.5.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)
$
```

Tengo estas versiones de rails:

```
$ gem list rails

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

autoprefixer-rails (9.7.5, 9.7.4, 9.7.3, 9.7.2, 9.7.1, 9.6.1.1, 9.4.5, 7.2.1, 7.1.4.1)
backstretch-rails (2.0.4)
bootstrap-datepicker-rails (1.9.0.1, 1.8.0.1, 1.7.1.1)
bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails (4.17.47)
bootstrap4-datetime-picker-rails (0.3.1)
capistrano-rails (1.4.0)
capistrano-rails-console (2.3.0)
coffee-rails (5.0.0, 4.2.2, 4.1.1, 4.0.1)
datetime_picker_rails (0.0.7)
dotenv-rails (2.7.5)
factory_girl_rails (4.9.0, 4.8.0, 4.4.1)
fancybox-rails (0.2.1)
font-awesome-rails (4.7.0.5, 4.7.0.4, 4.7.0.2)
graphiql-rails (1.7.0)
highcharts-rails (6.0.3)
jquery-datatables-rails (3.4.0)
jquery-rails (4.3.5, 4.3.1, 4.1.1, 3.1.1)
jquery-star-rating-rails (4.0.4)
jquery-ui-rails (5.0.0)
js_cookie_rails (2.2.0, 2.1.4)
jwplayer-rails (1.0.1)
lightbox-bootstrap-rails (5.1.0.1)
moment-timezone-rails (1.0.0)
momentjs-rails (2.20.1, 2.17.1)
ms-dropdown-rails (0.1.0)
pry-rails (0.3.9)
rails (5.2.4.2, 5.2.4.1, 5.2.4, 5.2.3, 5.1.7, 5.1.6.1, 5.1.5, 5.1.4, 5.1.3, 5.1.2, 5.0.7.2, 4.0.2)
rails-assets-jcrop (2.0.4)
rails-controller-testing (1.0.4)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-erd (1.6.0)
rails-footnotes (4.1.8)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0, 1.2.0, 1.0.4, 1.0.3)
rails-observers (0.1.5)
rails_autolink (1.1.6)
rails_emoji_picker (0.1.5)
rails_layout (1.0.42)
rspec-rails (3.9.0, 3.8.2, 3.6.0, 3.0.1)
sass-rails (6.0.0, 5.1.0, 5.0.7, 5.0.6, 4.0.3)
sassc-rails (2.1.2)
select2-rails (4.0.3)
selectize-rails (0.12.6, 0.12.4)
slim-rails (3.2.0, 3.1.2)
sprockets-rails (3.2.1, 3.2.0, 2.3.3, 2.0.1)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.8)
$
```

Este es mi SO:

```
$ uname -a
Linux IdeaPad 5.3.0-42-generic #34~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 13:42:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$
```

NOTA: No puedo adjuntar el archivo `Gemfile`, ni el `Gemfile.lock`, porque no se ejecuta el comando `$ rails new appname`

Comment: Cambiaste a la nueva version `2.5.5` despues de instalar, usando el comando `rvm use 2.5.5`?

Comment: Si claro, eso fue ño primero que chequee

Comment: Probaria de instalar otra versión (como prueba) y ver si funciona bien. Por ejemplo, la ultima versión estable `rvm install 2.7.1 && rvm use 2.7.1`

Comment: Si funciona también ya lo había hecho, pero no es viable en este momento ya que el proyecto está en producción y el único que tiene ese problema soy yo

Comment: Si me imaginaba que necesitabas esa versión específica por algún motivo. Puedes intentar `gem update --system`.

Comment: Con system update me camino, cuando arranco el server me dan 376 NOTE...... pero eso ya es otro tema,por lo menso camina, gracias